Why isn't weight paint affecting his suit correctly?
I made a model of him before and I did everything the same way I did before. The only difference, is that I put clothes on him. I weight painted the arms of his suit the same way as I did his arms, but the suit isn't following the bones like the arms do:c
I'll share a drive link with my blender file in case someone has time and will to look at it
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R6LDpK_TY4knD8Ma8WokY1or82znZknx?usp=sharing




Your normals are inverted, select all in Edit mode and press ShiftN to recalculate the normals, parent the mesh to the armature With Automatic Weights, you'll still need to make some corrections though:


you're a life saver!! Thank u so much! And merry Christmas C:
